# How to properly use include stdio.h in an NVRTC-compiled program?

Tags: c, cuda, runtime-compilation, nvrtc

I have written an amazing kernel which will bring me fame and fortune - if I can only get it to compile with NVRTC:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void do_stuff() { }
```

I would have hoped that system headers should be recognized by the (runtime) compiler, just like a regular compiler, and that this would "just work" (modulo any printf-specific machinery). Alternatively, if it didn't work, I would have expected an error message about `stdio.h`'s source not made available with the "program creation" API call ([`nvrtcCreateProgram()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html#group__compilation)), since I'm passing `NULL` and `NULL` as its last two arguments.

However, what I get is the following:

```
/usr/include/stdio.h(33): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "stddef.h"
```

This seems strange to me. It means that the runtime compiler *is* able to look inside system headers, but is *not* able to find `stddef.h`, like nvcc or the host side compiler are able to.

Why is this happening, and what is the idiomatic/recommended workaround?

Note: I'd like a workaround which would be cross-platform, not just work on my individual machine.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/jitify) may be of interest

Comment: Also related -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/50565200/681865 -- nvrtc shouldn't really be used with standard library headers. Use jitify, hack a feature set for the stdlib (not portable), or don't use them at all

Comment: @talonmies: But you need `stdio.h` for in-kernel `printf()`. Although to be frank the need to include always seemed extremely fishy to me, since you'r enot actually using the standard library's `printf()`.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: `jitify` is a great idea, but only in part. You see, it's somewhat of a self-contained "tower of babel"; it simplifies things for you doesn't mesh with other things you might be using; not to mention being a single 4K-line header file. However, within a few months I hope I am able to offer something nicer, or at least NVIDIA driver + nvrtc infrastructure that's nice enough to write jitify-like functionality on top of, with a lot less code.

Comment: My point was that nvrtc is really intended for "pure" and "simple" CUDA code which compiles without a lot of the standard library parsing and manipulation which the nvcc front end handles. I would never use printf in something I was going to JIT compile

Comment: @talonmies: 1. Well, sometimes the code can't be known apriori and you can't help it. And - trying to use a debug with JIT-compiled code is no more fun than `printf()`ing. Of course when you're done with it and eveything works, you drop things like `printf()` 2. CUDA code is not pure and simple. If I want to compile pure and simple code I'll compile PTX... :-P

Comment: @talonmies: Well, now we have [this self-contained `printf`-family implementation](https://github.com/eyalroz/printf/tree/cuda-support) that's usable in CUDA kernels, JIT or otherwise; and the implementation can be compiled in advance, so this doesn't inflate the kernel code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An additional approach is taken in the "JITify" library which Robert Crovella has graciously reminded me of. While this doesn't seem to be documented very well, Jitify pre-includes processed snippets of various headers it sees fit to. In particular for `<climits>`/`<limits.h>`:

```
static const char* jitsafe_header_limits_h = R"(
#pragma once
#if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
 #define __WORDSIZE 32
#else
 #if defined __x86_64__ && !defined __ILP32__
  #define __WORDSIZE 64
 #else
  #define __WORDSIZE 32
 #endif
#endif
#define MB_LEN_MAX  16
#define CHAR_BIT    8
#define SCHAR_MIN   (-128)
#define SCHAR_MAX   127
#define UCHAR_MAX   255
enum {
  _JITIFY_CHAR_IS_UNSIGNED = (char)-1 >= 0,
  CHAR_MIN = _JITIFY_CHAR_IS_UNSIGNED ? 0 : SCHAR_MIN,
  CHAR_MAX = _JITIFY_CHAR_IS_UNSIGNED ? UCHAR_MAX : SCHAR_MAX,
};
#define SHRT_MIN    (-32768)
#define SHRT_MAX    32767
#define USHRT_MAX   65535
#define INT_MIN     (-INT_MAX - 1)
#define INT_MAX     2147483647
#define UINT_MAX    4294967295U
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
 # define LONG_MAX  9223372036854775807L
#else
 # define LONG_MAX  2147483647L
#endif
#define LONG_MIN    (-LONG_MAX - 1L)
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
 #define ULONG_MAX  18446744073709551615UL
#else
 #define ULONG_MAX  4294967295UL
#endif
#define LLONG_MAX  9223372036854775807LL
#define LLONG_MIN  (-LLONG_MAX - 1LL)
#define ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615ULL
)";
```

for `stddef.h`:

```
static const char* jitsafe_header_stddef_h =
    "#pragma once\n"
    "#include <climits>\n"
    "namespace __jitify_stddef_ns {\n"
    "#if __cplusplus >= 201103L\n"
    "typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;\n"
    "#if defined(_MSC_VER)\n"
    "  typedef double max_align_t;\n"
    "#elif defined(__APPLE__)\n"
    "  typedef long double max_align_t;\n"
    "#else\n"
    "  // Define max_align_t to match the GCC definition.\n"
    "  typedef struct {\n"
    "    long long __jitify_max_align_nonce1\n"
    "        __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long long))));\n"
    "    long double __jitify_max_align_nonce2\n"
    "        __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long double))));\n"
    "  } max_align_t;\n"
    "#endif\n"
    "#endif  // __cplusplus >= 201103L\n"
    "#if __cplusplus >= 201703L\n"
    "enum class byte : unsigned char {};\n"
    "#endif  // __cplusplus >= 201703L\n"
    "} // namespace __jitify_stddef_ns\n"
    "namespace std {\n"
    "  // NVRTC provides built-in definitions of ::size_t and ::ptrdiff_t.\n"
    "  using ::size_t;\n"
    "  using ::ptrdiff_t;\n"
    "  using namespace __jitify_stddef_ns;\n"
    "} // namespace std\n"
    "using namespace __jitify_stddef_ns;\n";
```

and for `stdio.h`:

```
static const char* jitsafe_header_stdio_h =
    "#pragma once\n"
    "#include <stddef.h>\n"
    "#define FILE int\n"
    "int fflush ( FILE * stream );\n"
    "int fprintf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );\n";
```

If you include those strings as headers, with the appropriate names as keys, it is likely your kernel will compile.

In fact, one could form header files out of these and other mini-headers in `jitify.hpp`, to use in non-NVRTC kernel compilation. That might be useful too.

One last point: The constants above do not specify a `__device__` execution space. So, either you add `__device__` in there, or tell the compiler to assume functions are intended for execution on the device only, unless otherwise specified; that's the `--device-as-default-execution-space` NVRTC compiler option.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions which might work, but which I would rather *avoid*. If they're the only reasonable course of action after all - please comment and say so:

1. Add the specific path to `stddef.h` as a compiler parameter (`-I` or `--include-path=`).
2. Pass the source of `stddef.h` to the `nvrtcCreateProgram()` call.